# Is this a metric space?

Tags: metric-spaces, triangle-inequality

Let $d: \mathbb{C}\times\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ defined by

$d(x,y) = \frac{|x-y|}{\sqrt{1+|x|^2}+\sqrt{1+|y|^2}}$

All the properties of $d$ can easily be satisfied.

I proved that $d$ is a bounded metric while trying to solve this. By

$\frac{|x-y|}{\sqrt{1+|x|^2}+\sqrt{1+|y|^2}} \le \frac{|x|+|y|}{|x|+|y|}=1$

But I can't find a way to prove or disprove the triangle inequality. Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: "Although, the addition in between the square roots in the denominator was replaced by the multiplication sign." So, do you want to check if the one with addition is a metric or the one with multiplication? Regardless, what have you tried?

Comment: well with multiplication was not so tough. by using the cauchy schwartz inequality. Yes I have tried. for far too long. And concluded that the metric is bounded. but can't reach the conclusion for triangle inequality. I also tried by substituting some value for x and y to see if the inequality is inconsistent with z. But can't pin point a way to proof so.